Question on the proof of localization of tensor product isomorphic to tensor product of localization
I have seen some posts here that talks about the isomorphism between the localization of a tensor product and the tensor product of localization, but I am not sure if I am understunding it.
For example, here the user shows the same morphism I was thinking about and also writes its inverse, but anyone shows that this inverse is well-defined with respect the localization of the tensor product, what it is shown in the answers is directly the isomorphy by using propperties of the tensor product.
My question is, can we prove that in fact that inverse map is well-defined? I am very confused since the Universal propperty for Localization is only mentioned for rings on my Commutative algebra book, not for modules.
Moreover, if it can not be proven directly that the inverse map is well-defined, why the chain of ismorphism equalities on the Modules would imply that that the given morphism is an isomorphism?

The chain of isomorphisms is given by the map that OP constructs in one direction. This can be verified explicitly. It is also possible to write down the inverse map explicitly, but you will have to convince yourself of the universal property of the localization of modules (this is a special case of extension/restriction of scalars) if you haven't seen it before.

@Thorgott Then, how can I prove the universal property? Given $M, N$ $A$-modules and $S \subset A$ multiplicative, we should be able to define for every morphism $f : M \rightarrow N$ a morphism $F : M_S \rightarrow N$ such that $F = f \circ \pi$ where $\pi : M \rightarrow M_S$ is the quotient morphism. The problem is, $\pi$ is not necessarily surjective as it occurs, for example, on topological quotients , I mean, not every $m/s \in M_S$ has a $n \in M: \pi(n) = m/s$, true? Or did I leave something?

That is not the right universal property. The correct property is as follows: If $M$ is an $A$-module and $N$ an $S^{-1}A$-module, any $S^{-1}A$-linear map $f\colon M_S\rightarrow N$ restricts along $\pi$ to an $A$-linear map $M\rightarrow N$ (here, we interpret $N$ as an $A$-module) and this correspondence is in fact bijective.

But, what I want to prove is that the map $M \otimes_A N \rightarrow M_S \otimes_{A_S} N_S, x \otimes y \mapsto \frac{x}{1} \otimes \frac{y}{1}$ extends to $(M \otimes_A N)_S$, not that restricts. The extension should be defined as $\frac{x \otimes y}{s} \mapsto \frac{x}{s} \otimes  \frac{y}{1}$

I'm saying that restricting yields a bijection. That is, any $A$-linear map $M\rightarrow N$ extends uniquely to an $S^{-1}A$-linear map $M_S\rightarrow N$ along $\pi$.

@Thorgott You are so right, thanks for your answer! I have proved for myself the bijectiveness, it works perfectly. If I do not bother you, when we have those well-defined morphism, it is easy to prove that they are inverse on the elementary tensors. How this generalize to the full tensor product?

Every tensor is a sum of elementary tensors and the homomorphisms are additive.
